# When do column indexes become "worth it"

Tags: sql-server

For any given single table that has more than 1 column that you look up against using a `WHERE` clause, where those columns are `int` or `bigint`, at what point does it become worth creating an index on those columns.

I am aware that i should create those columns anyway, this question is about when does the performance advantage of having those indexes there, kick in in terms of table size.

Comment: When not having them hurts more than having them. There is no heuristic to determine this - a database is a living machine, you need to keep checking on it and massaging the indexes and statistics into a healthy DB.

Comment: It depends. If all of the rows in the table contain the same value (or say, there's a 50/50 split between two possible values) then it's highly unlikely that the index will ever be selective enough to benefit a query.

Answer (score 0):

Instantly, granted you wouldn't notice it on a small table, but it needs to do a table scan if an index isn't in place on these columns.

So in execution time you wouldn't notice it but if you look at CPU used by the query, and reads you'll notice with the index the query instantly start performing better.

Answer (score 0):

The advantage would happen when data must be retrieved and the most restrictive where clause involve the indexed column

Note that: On CUD statement, indexes will add an overhead (which might be compensated if the CUD involve some data retrieving such as explained above).